# Creating a todos list using react-infinite-scroller

Tags: javascript, reactjs, infinite-scroll

Trying to create a list of todos using `react-infinite-scroller`. The list will display 20 todos, the next todos will be displayed while scrolling. I fetch Todos from 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos'. The fetched todos are saved in the `todos` variable.

I've modeled this example: https://github.com/CassetteRocks/react-infinite-scroller/blob/master/docs/src/index.js.

Demo here: https://cassetterocks.github.io/react-infinite-scroller/demo/.

I can not see `Loading..` appearing and fetching further tasks.

Code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tcm9o2?file=index.js

```
import InfiniteScroll from 'react-infinite-scroller';
import qwest from 'qwest';

class App extends Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      todos: [],
      hasMoreTodos: true,
      nextHref: null
    }
  }

  loadTodos(page){
     var self = this;
    const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos';

    if(this.state.nextHref) {
      url = this.state.nextHref;
    }

    qwest.get(url, {
      linked_partitioning: 1,
      page_size: 10
    }, {
      cache: true
    })
    .then((xhr, resp) => {
      if(resp) {
        var todos = self.state.todos;
        resp.map((todo) => {

          todos.push(todo);
        });

        if(resp.next_href) {
          self.setState({
            todos: todos,
            nextHref: resp.next_href
          });
        } else {
          self.setState({
              hasMoreTodos: false
          });
        }
      }
    });
  }


  render () {
    const loader = <div className="loader">Loading ...</div>;
    console.log(this.state.todos);

    var items = [];
    this.state.todos.map((todo, i) => {
        items.push(
            <div className="track" key={todo.id}>
              <p className="title">{todo.title}</p>
            </div>
        );
    });


    return (
      <InfiniteScroll
            pageStart={0}
            loadMore={this.loadTodos.bind(this)}
            hasMore={this.state.hasMoreTodos}
            loader={loader}>
        <div className="tracks">
          {items}
        </div>
      </InfiniteScroll>
    )
  }
}
```

**UPDATED MY QUESTION**

How can I set these places commented in the code?

```
/*if(this.state.nextHref) {
    url = this.state.nextHref;
}*/

and

 /*if(resp.next_href) {
  self.setState({
    todos: todos,
    nextHref: resp.next_href
  });*/
```

How can I set the page to change from 1 to 2, next from 2 to 3?

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      todos: [],
      hasMoreTodos: true,
      page: 1
    }
  }

  loadTodos(page){
    var self = this;

    const url = `/api/v1/project/tasks?expand=todos&filter%5Btype%5D=400&${page}&${per_page}`;

    /*if(this.state.nextHref) {
      url = this.state.nextHref;
    }*/

    axios.get(url, {
      'page': 1,
      'per-page': 10
    })
    .then(resp => {
      if(resp) {
        var todos = [self.state.todos, ...resp];

        /*if(resp.next_href) {
          self.setState({
            todos: todos,
            nextHref: resp.next_href
          });*/
        } else {
          self.setState({
              hasMoreTodos: false
          });
        }
      }
    });
  }


  render () {
    const loader = <div className="loader">Loading ...</div>;

    var divStyle = {
       'width': '100px';
       'height': '300px';
       'border': '1px solid black',
       'scroll': 'auto'
    };

    const items = this.state.todos.map((todo, i) => 
        <div className="track" key={todo.id}>
            <p className="title">{todo.title}</p>
        </div>);


    return (
        <div style={divStyle}>
            <InfiniteScroll
                pageStart={1}
                loadMore={this.loadTodos.bind(this)}
                hasMore={this.state.hasMoreTodos}
                loader={loader}>
            <div className="tracks">
                {items}
            </div>
            </InfiniteScroll>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**UPDATED 2**

Code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-4lwucm

```
import InfiniteScroll from 'react-infinite-scroller';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      todos: [],
      hasMoreTodos: true,
      page: 1,
      nextPage: 1,
      finishedLoading: false
    };
  }


  loadTodos = (id) => {
    if(!this.state.finishedLoading) {
      const params = {
        id: '1234',
        page: this.state.nextPage,
        'per-page': 10,
      }

      axios({
        url: `/api/v1/project/tasks`,
        method: "GET",
        params
      })
      .then(res => { 
        let {todos, nextPage} = this.state;

        if(resp) {    //resp or resp.data ????
          this.setState({
            todos: [...todos, ...resp], //resp or resp.data ????
            nextPage: nextPage + 1,
            finishedLoading: resp.length > 0 //resp or resp.data ????
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      }) 
    }
  }

  render() {
    const loader = <div className="loader">Loading ...</div>;
    const divStyle = {
      'height': '300px',
      'overflow': 'auto',
      'width': '200px',
      'border': '1px solid black'
    }

   const items = this.state.todos.map((todo, i) => 
    <div className="track" key={todo.id}>
      <p className="title">{todo.title}</p>
    </div>);

    return (
      <div style={divStyle} ref={(ref) => this.scrollParentRef = ref}>
        <div>
            <InfiniteScroll
              pageStart={0}
              loadMore={this.loadTodos}
              hasMore={true || false}
              loader={<div className="loader" key={0}>Loading ...</div>}
              useWindow={false}
              getScrollParent={() => this.scrollParentRef}
            >
                {items}
            </InfiniteScroll>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: given `cache: true` - did you clear/disable the cache before testing?

Comment: @Aprillion Where I can clear/disable the cache. In develooper tools in network Tab I have checked the checkbox 'disable cache' but it doesn't work

Comment: It works for me, loading the 200 items at one though. One (unrelated?) thing though: your use of [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is technically wrong. Use [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) if you're interested in the side-effect produced by your callback rather than its return value.

Comment: hugo it does not work for me. Elements are downloaded right away. At the time of scrolling, they should be charged. There should be 10 elements displayed and they are all

Comment: I did not mean browser cache, but the feature that is implemented by `qwest` that is set by `cache: true` configuration - I have no idea how that one works, but presumably changing it to `cache: false` for the testing might help... In case the very detailed answer does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*EDIT:* I just realized you used [this](https://github.com/CassetteRocks/react-infinite-scroller/blob/master/docs/src/index.js) as a starting point:

## Why you get everything at once

Well, because your source is just a big JSON.

The logic in the script you're using is adapted to SoundCloud's API, which paginates (aka. returns chunk-by-chunk) the enormous list.

Your API doesn't paginate, hence why you're receiving everything at once.

See an example result from the SoundCloud API:

```
{
    "collection": [
        {
            "kind": "track",
            "id": 613085994,
            "created_at": "2019/04/29 13:25:27 +0000",
            "user_id": 316489116,
            "duration": 476281,
            [...]
        },
        [...]
    ],
    "next_href": "https://api.soundcloud.com/users/8665091/favorites?client_id=caf73ef1e709f839664ab82bef40fa96&cursor=1550315585694796&linked_partitioning=1&page_size=10"
}
```

The URL in `next_href` gives the URL of the next batch of items (the URL is the same but the 'cursor' parameter is different each time). That's what makes the infinite list work: each time, it gets the next batch.

**You have to implement server-side pagination to achieve this result.**

In response to your edit:

> UPDATED MY QUESTION
>
> How can I set these places commented in the code?
>
> ```
> /*if(this.state.nextHref) {
>     url = this.state.nextHref; }*/
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> /*if(resp.next_href) {   self.setState({
>     todos: todos,
>     nextHref: resp.next_href   });*/
> ```

Forget about loading the nextHref, you don't have that. What you have is the current page number (up to which page you have loaded the contents).

Try something along the lines of:

```
if (!self.state.finishedLoading) {
  qwest.get("https://your-api.org/json", {
    page: self.state.nextPage,
    'per-page': 10,
  }, {
    cache: true
  })
  .then((xhr, resp) => {
    let {todos, nextPage} = self.state;

    if(resp) {
      self.setState({
        todos: [...todos, ...resp],
        nextPage: nextPage + 1,
        finishedLoading: resp.length > 0, // stop loading when you don't get any more results
      });
    }
  });
}
```

## A few nitpicks

Here you are mutating `self.state` [(bad)](https://daveceddia.com/why-not-modify-react-state-directly/), in addition to using `Array.map` with a side-effect (and for that side-effect only) :

```
    var todos = self.state.todos;
    resp.map((todo) => {
      todos.push(todo);
    });
```

You could write it as:

```
    var todos = [self.state.todos, ...resp];
```

Same usage of map here:

```
var items = [];
this.state.todos.map((todo, i) => {
    items.push(
        <div className="track" key={todo.id}>
          <p className="title">{todo.title}</p>
        </div>
    );
});
```

Should be written:

```
const items = this.state.todos.map((todo, i) => 
    <div className="track" key={todo.id}>
      <p className="title">{todo.title}</p>
    </div>);
```

Comment: In my real api I have pagination: example:`page=2&per-page=20`. Can I use it? linked_partitioning === page ?  page_size === per-page?  What is "next_href"? I have only page, per-page

Comment: Then can you show an example with your real API? 'next_href' is the API returning the URL for the next page, so you don't have to figure it out client-side, which is pretty neat. If your API doesn't do that, it's no big deal, you just have to make sure the client increments X in `page=X`

Comment: Very nice that you posted a working and testable example, but it would be easier to help if you updated it to call your actual API (or one that works similarly).

Comment: Do I have to use qwest? Can I use axios?

Comment: Use whatever you want as long as it gets the data from your URL.

Comment: I updated my question. How can I set these places commented in the code? How can I set the page to change from 1 to 2 when changing from 2 to 3?

Comment: See my update. You may have to change a few things but I believe it does what you want.

Comment: In constructor in this.state I have to set: ` hasMoreTodos: true,
      page: 1,
      finishedLoading: false,
      nextPage: 1` ?

Comment: Have you tried it? did it work? if not what's the problem? -- come on, by this point you can do it, I'm sure (btw you don't need 'page' in your state if you use 'nextPage')

Comment: In network tab I see good request. It fetch 10 todos. In console.log I see 20 todos, 10 todos plus 10 doubled

Comment: The list shows me twenty tasks. At the end you can see Loading ... You can not see any infinity scroll, display all at the same time

Comment: tried this way: https://github.com/alexcambose/react-infinite-scroll. It will download 10, there is no further fetching

Comment: I am trying this way. Custom parent element, not Window scroll events
Https: //github.com/CassetteRocks/react-infinite-scroller

Comment: Update your stackblitz and I may be able to help you, it's hard to guess. Have you tried to find out *why* it doesn't fetch? Does it stop entering the `if`? Does it send a request that times out? Does it successfully get the data but doesnt update correctly the view? (those are the questions you should ask yourself)

Comment: I have to do it relative to the parent element. As shown in the picture

Comment: Gets only the first 10. A in the console displays in the array 20 (10 todos plus 10 duplicates (. There are no more fetching, sending requests.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197525/discussion-between-hugo-and-umbro).

Comment: Did you check it?

Comment: No, sorry, I have a day job... I can check it later

Comment: The URL doesn't work... how could I know whether it should be "resp or resp.data" if I can't even load the file?

Comment: @I can't give you the real URL, I would have to provide ClientId, password

Comment: Honestly, can you mark Hugo's answer as the correct one. I've never seen someone spend so much time and care to answer a question before.

Comment: @iMacAnge Thank you -- that would be appreciated indeed :)

Comment: it's usually considered negative to get good, constructive answers to your question and not mark it as positive and give the promised bounty. @Hugo has obviously put a lot of effort into a very high quality answer that answers your original question and then some.